# How to use a helper generic of type class of type

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe6

I am trying to figure out how to *genericize* this helper method; so that it returns the same type that was asked for:

```
type
    TScreenHelper = class helper for TScreen
    public
        function FindForm(DesiredFormClass: TFormClass): TForm;
    end;
```

Right now the caller has to cast the return value to type they already want:

```
var
   frmReportReminderSetup: TfrmReportReminderSetup;
begin
   //frmReportReminderSetup := Screen.FindForm(TfrmReportReminderSetup); Doesn't compile

   frmReportReminderSetup := TfrmReportReminderSetup(Screen.FindForm(TfrmReportReminderSetup));
```

The non-generic implementation is:

```
function TScreenHelper.FindForm(DesiredFormClass: TFormClass): TForm;
var
    f: TForm;
    i: Integer;
begin
    Result := nil;

    for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 do //Screen.Forms does not support enumeration
    begin
        f := Screen.Forms[i];

        if (f is DesiredFormClass) then
        begin
            Result := f;
            Exit;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

## Generics

What i want is some way to use generics so that the function returns the type it was asked for.

```
frmContoso := Screen.FindForm(TfrmContoso);
```

In pseudo-code, the signature that i want would be something like:

```
function FindForm(T: TFormClass): T;
```

When it comes time to turn this into actual Delphi syntax, i *think* you must specify one of the  **T** references in angle brackets:

```
function FindForm(<T>): T;
```

But i don't think the  is allowed there; i think it has to be before the opening parenthesis:

```
function FindForm<T>: T;
```

### Try that

```
TScreenHelper = class helper for TScreen
public
    function FindFormOld(DesiredFormClass: TFormClass): TForm;
    function FindForm<T>: T;
end;

function TScreenHelper.FindForm<T>: T;
var
    f: TForm;
    i: Integer;
begin
    Result := nil;

    for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 do //Screen.Forms does not support enumeration
    begin
        f := Screen.Forms[i];

        if (f is T) then
        begin
            Result := f as T;
            Exit;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Except that fails to compile:

```
Result := nil;  E2010 Incompatible types: 'T' and 'Pointer'
```

I can sorta see what's wrong. It doesn't understand that **T** is a class (i.e. what if it was an `Integer`? Then it would absolutely be wrong to set it to `nil`.)

## Constraints

So i need to somehow give the compiler the hint of what type `T` **will** be:

```
TScreenHelper = class helper for TScreen
public
    function FindForm<T: TFormClass>: T;
end;

function TScreenHelper.FindForm<T: TFormClass>: T;
var
    f: TForm;
    i: Integer;
begin
    Result := nil;

    for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 do //Screen.Forms does not support enumeration
    begin
        f := Screen.Forms[i];

        if (f is T) then
        begin
            Result := f as T;
            Exit;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

This new signature is confusing to call; you no longer **pass** a desired type to the function. Instead you now **call** a variation of the function that you want:

```
frmContoso := Screen.FindForm<TfrmConsoto>();
```

But no matter; it's way of generics.

## Except that's not valid

The syntax:

```
function FindForm<T: TFormClass>: T;
```

is not valid, as `TFormClass` is not one of the allowed Delphi constraint types:

> ### [Constraints in Generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Constraints_in_Generics)
>
> **Specifying Generics with Constraints**
>
> Constraint items include:
>
> - Zero, one, or multiple interface types
> - **Zero or one class type**
> - The reserved word "constructor", "class", or "record"

*(emphasis mine)*

While i'm allowed *one class type*, i'm not passing a class type; i'm passing a **class of class** type.

So now i'm stuck. In my attempt to save myself typing 25 characters, i've now blown an hour on the minutia of Delphi generics.

## tl;dr

How do i *genericize*:

```
function FindForm(DesiredFormClass: TFormClass): TForm;
```

### Example non-working code

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Vcl.Forms;

type
    TScreenHelperCore = class(TObject)
    public
        class function FindForm<T: TForm>: T;
    end;

    TfrmContoso = class(TForm)
    public

   end;

{ TScreenHelperCore }

class function TScreenHelperCore.FindForm<T: TForm>: T; 
//                                         \__[dcc32 Error] Project2.dpr(23): E2029 ',', ';' or '>' expected but ':' found
var
    f: TForm;
    i: Integer;
begin
    Result := nil;

    for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 do //Screen.Forms does not support enumeration
    begin
        f := Screen.Forms[i];

        if (f is T) then
        begin
            Result := f;
            Exit;
        end;
    end;
end;

var
    f: TfrmContoso;

begin
  try
        f := TScreenHelperCore.FindForm<TfrmContoso>;
        if f = nil then
            f := TfrmContoso.Create(nil);

        f.ShowModal;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Ian @XE6!? What happened to D5? ;)

Comment: How come I know who wrote this question after only reading 3-4 pages :)

Comment: @NGLN Keep up with the times. We've moved on!!

Comment: @LURD Indeed. I got it from the first page on my phone!

Comment: @NGLN My employer decided to fork over the $3,000 for a new version. And three months later the bugridden upgrade is already out of date :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constraint is wrong. Instead of

```
function FindForm<T: TFormClass>: T;
```

you need

```
function FindForm<T: TForm>: T;
```

You are going to instantiate this generic type with `TMyForm` rather than `class of TMyForm`.

And you must only state the constraint in the declaration of the class and not in its implementation.   Here's a complete program that compiles:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  Vcl.Forms;

type
  TScreenHelper = class helper for TScreen
  public
    function FindForm<T: TForm>: T;
  end;

function TScreenHelper.FindForm<T>: T;
var
  f: TForm;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
  begin
    f := Screen.Forms[i];
    if (f is T) then
    begin
      Result := T(f);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := nil;
end;

type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  end;

var
  Form: TMyForm;

begin
  Form := Screen.FindForm<TMyForm>;
end.
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct syntax? I get `E2029 ',', ';' or '>' expected but ':' found` right in middle of `T:`. Also, if `T` is constrained to be of type `TForm`, then wouldn't i be required to have a type of `TForm`?

Comment: Compiles here in my XE7. I take the code in your constraints section and change TFormClass to TForm. And remove the constraint in the implementation. No need to repeat yourself.

Comment: I've updated the question to include a complete non-functional console test-app. Can you show me your code, so we can compare why yours doesn't not compile?

Comment: Yes, you said it was not possible to have generics in a helper. So i removed the extraneous confusion. I can wrap a call to `TScreenHelperCore` from the helper class `TScreenHelper` if you'd like. I could also delete the question, and ask it again, except remove references to *"helper"* can focus strictly on the *"generics"* issue.

Comment: Turns out that I was wrong. What do I know?! You need to find a real expert.

Comment: At least we've solved one problem. The question isn't how to use generics constrained to *"class of class"*. I can't even get a generic constraint to compile. The conundrum now is do i create a new question about how to use constraints in generics? Then another question of how to use constraints with *class of* generics. If that preamble is solved, hopefully then this question can be answered.

Comment: I think all problems are solved surely? Or does my code compile in my compiler but not yours?

Comment: `TScreenHelperCore.FindForm<TfrmContoso>;` gives **E2010 Incompatible types: 'TfrmContoso' and 'TForm'**

Comment: I think you need to slow down a little. The code in my answer compiles. You need to understand why constraining a generic parameter to be `class of T` is wrong, and that you must state the constraint exactly once. Then I think we'll be done.

Comment: Yes, the problem i didn't realize is that the constraint in the implementation section isn't optional, it's **forbidden**. After that it was the simple matter of the wooden mallet being applied to skull for me to remember that `T` **is** for a type.

Comment: Well, I also learnt that the constraint must be specified exactly once. Thanks for that.